# how to indent "margin-right" for the first and third <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a "provide" block in which I need to do "margin-right" only for the first and third blocks "blok1

I tried `nth-child()`, but nothing worked

```
<div class = "provide">
                <div class = "blok1">
                    <img class = "photo" src ="img/settings.jpg">
                    <h3>Management</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
               <img class = "photo" src ="img/pencil.jpg">
                    <h3>UI /UX Design</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/diamond.jpg">
                    <h3>Logo / Branding</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/truck%202.jpg">
                    <h3>Animation</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet, consect netur.</h4>
                </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: how did you try `nth-child()`? Did you also specify the index inside the pseudoclass?

Comment: @ShawnSpencer "nth-child is poorly supported" - really? Try searching for `nth-child()` (with parentheses). https://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child()

Comment: @Turnip - My bad and my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.provide > .blok1:first-child, .provide > .blok1:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

or

```
.provide > .blok1:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I tried 
.blok1:nth-of-type(1),
.blok1:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-right:10px;
}
It works!

Comment: If any of the answers here helped you, I would appreciate if you mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a new class name to the existing ones and apply CSS to those. In this case, I have written a class **.myBlock** to the existing class **blok1**. Keeping this in mind I have prepared a code snippet for you with the desired output.

```css
.myBlock{
margin-right:100px
}
```

```html
<div class = "provide">
                <div class = "blok1 myBlock">
                    <img class = "photo" src ="img/settings.jpg">
                    <h3>Management</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
               <img class = "photo" src ="img/pencil.jpg">
                    <h3>UI /UX Design</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1 myBlock">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/diamond.jpg">
                    <h3>Logo / Branding</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/truck%202.jpg">
                    <h3>Animation</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet, consect netur.</h4>
                </div>
     </div>
```

**Make sure you change the margin-right's value to your desired value. I have kept it as 100px to show you how it works.**

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work.
```

```css
.provide .blok1:first-child,
.provide .blok1:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 36px;
}
.blok1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "provide">
                <div class = "blok1">
                    <img class = "photo" src ="img/settings.jpg">
                    <h3>Management</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
               <img class = "photo" src ="img/pencil.jpg">
                    <h3>UI /UX Design</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/diamond.jpg">
                    <h3>Logo / Branding</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet,</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "blok1">
                <img class = "photo" src ="img/truck%202.jpg">
                    <h3>Animation</h3>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit  adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor sit amet, consect netur.</h4>
                </div>
     </div>
```